# Using Python and external programs

Tags: python, .net, cmd

By using python, how do I use cmd.exe supported commands and get the output to be viewed back in python?
The reason I am doing this is to get the Microsoft .NET framework version. At the moment I could only find it through the cmd.exe by using the following command:

```
wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft .Net%'" get Name, Version
```

So I was thinking to get python to execute the above command and get the results back and write them to a file.

Comment: What cmd command you are using?

Comment: "wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft .Net%'" get Name, Version" This is what i use to get the framework details.. if I could get python to get the details to be stored in a notepad, that would also be great..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way about how to execute cmd command from python using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

**Code**: The following code is just pinging the loopback address using `ping 127.0.0.1` command and then writing the results to a file. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for file handling in python could be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

```
import subprocess

def myFunc():   
    p = subprocess.Popen("ping 127.0.0.1", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    print out
    print err
    with open('myOutputFile.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(out) #Write the output to a file
myFunc()
```

Replace the `ping 127.0.0.1` with other cmd command and it should work. For eg: `netstat -a`.

Note: It might take a while before you see the output in console, because the output will be returned to the console when the cmd command has finished the execution!

The following code should do your job:

```
import subprocess

def myFunc():   
    p = subprocess.Popen("wmic product where \"Name like 'Microsoft .Net%'\" get Name, Version", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    print out
    print err
    with open('myOutputFile.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(out) #Write the output to a file
myFunc()
```

Hope it helps!